# Show that {x_n} does not converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the sequence:

$\{x_n\}$ defined as $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1} =x_n + \frac 1{2x_n}$, $n\ge1$

1) show that $\{x_n\}$ doesnt converge.
ok so I found out that the sequence is increasing and normaly if I were to check if the sequence was converging I would just try to find lim xn, so a=a+1/2a which give 0=1/2a? this clearly didnt work out, so im wondering how do I go about showing a sequence isnt converging in situations like this?

2) is $\{x_n\}$ bounded?

I would guess no? since its increasing and divergent? or am I wrong?

so anyone have any tips or solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Well if a sequence is increasing and divergent, it must be unbounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Since $x_{n+1}^2 = \left(x_n+\dfrac{1}{2x_n}\right)^2 = x_n^2+1+\dfrac{1}{4x_n^2} \ge x_n^2+1$ and $x_1^2 = 1$, you can show by induction that $x_n^2 \ge n$ for all integers $n \ge 1$.